# System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'

Tags: c#, memory, computer-vision

Today, I wanna to scan some QR codes using C#. Because, why no?
So, I am using Emgu (package from NuGet), and when I am trying to save image, I receive this error.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'
```

This is code I am using:

```
Capture capture = new Capture(); //create a camera capture
Bitmap image = capture.QueryFrame().Bitmap; //take a picture
image.Save((path + "data" + i.ToString() + ".jpg").Replace(" ", "_"));
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Use Path.Combine to create a proper file path and name.  That "Replace" looks wrong because it would change the path since "i" is presumably a number.

Comment: Which of the lines you posted throws the error? Show us the [entire error message](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=A generic error occurred in GDI+.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename)
   at Demo.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\dev\source\repos\Demo\Demo\Program.cs:line 24

Answer (score 1):

Ran across this and found that my issue was resolved by specifying a format in the save:

```
bmpImage.Save(filename,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix some path error:

```
string path = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, "img" + i.ToString() + ".jpg");
```

Comment: I ran into the same error running the save command to a memory stream instead of a file. So I don't think it's a path error.

Comment: I'm not sure why it errors. Perhaps an invalid bitmap being passed in? My "hack" work around was just to try/catch the save statement and retry capturing the image.